# QueryString checking

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check if the web page contains any string queries at the page load?

Comment: Do you mean QueryString?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can determine if there are any values in the QueryString by checking its count:

```
Request.QueryString.Count > 0;
```

That said if you are trying to prevent a page from erroring because you don't want to access a value that is not there I recommend wrapping query parms up in page properties and returning safe values from the property.

As an example

```
// setting this as protected makes it available in markup
protected string TaskName
{
    get { return (string)Request.QueryString["VarName"] ?? String.Empty; }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Check for

```
Request.QueryString["QueryStringName"]
```

if you know the particular name and it returns null if there isn't any querystring by that name

or if you want to check the count of querystrings then

```
Request.QueryString.Count
```

and check against 0. If greater than 0 then there is atleast 1 string appended.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the page was accessed with *any* query string, you can check the Count property:

```
bool expression = Request.QueryString.Count > 0;
```

To access a defined query string parameter, you can do it like this:

```
string myParam = Request.QueryString["MyParam"];
```

myParam will be null if it is not on the URL.

Comment: But there isn't any length property

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
{
    //Code here
}
else
{
  //Code here
}
```